# Windows arranged strangely on multiple desktop after detaching external monitor

Tags: 12.04, unity, multiple-monitors

Most of the time when I'm working, I have 4 windows open (editor, browser, mail client, terminal), and I use the multiple virtual desktops feature to put one on each window. So instead of alt-tabbing, I move to a different desktop.

The issue is that when I have them arranged on the desktops correctly and then disconnect my external monitor, they're all moved to the same desktop. When I plug the external monitor back in, then some of them are moved to the external, whereas some are still on the laptop display. Either way, it makes being mobile a very jarring experience.

Is there some way to "fix" or configure this behaviour?

Comment: I'm still having the exact same problem on 12.10, and the bug ticket on launchpas doesn't seem to be in progress. Has anyone found a solution to stop this? Of course I can always get my windows back manually after pluging/unpluging the monitor, but it's pretty boring when you plug your laptop twice a day.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in Compiz and filed here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/763148

I agree it is very tedious. If you have any extra info to add, or to mark the bug as affecting you, use the link above.

Answer (score 0):

If you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the window you want to select, you should be able to move it even if you can't see it. Try typing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd>, or <kbd>→</kbd>. That moves the window around.

Another thing to try is to alt-tab to the window you want, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and an arrow. It should move the windows to the desktop you are on. But I think the first solution is more likely.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been using to get them in the right place, but every time I (dis)connect the external monitor, it screws up all the placement. Very frustrating.

Comment: This happens in some Windows and Mac applications too. I'm not sure what component would be to blame. Video Driver, OS, The program, Gnome/Unity... But it's not just an Ubuntu thing, so it must be a fair bit tricky to come up with a consistent solution.

Comment: I don't think the video driver would be in charge of window placement... it's clearly something the OS *should* be in control of.